# Support multiple screens programmatically

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I'm writing an application for Android and I have difficulties with supporting multiple screen programmatically. I have a button which is jumping on the screen randomly. This is the code:

```
Random r = new Random();
x = r.nextInt(250 - 80);
y = r.nextInt(300 - 80);

btn.setX(x); 
btn.setY(y);
```

What I'm struggle with is do it for every screen size. Now as you can see my button is jumping to a random place but only on a 250*300 size of screens. How can I do my app to recognize the screen sizes and change the numbers? Or I should use another code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to programmatically to get the dimensions of the screen.

```
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

        mWindowWidth = size.x;
        mWindowHeight = size.y;
    } else {
        Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
        mWindowWidth = d.getWidth();
        mWindowHeight = d.getHeight();
    }
```

Importantly, do not forget to check orientation.

```
private String getScreenOrientation(){    
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        return "ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT";
    else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        return "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE";
    else
        return "";
}
```

But better study [this code](https://gist.github.com/SammyVimes/92c0627195c4c55ea800).

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see below code hope it will help you

```
int x ,y ;
int width,height;

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;



Random r = new Random();
x = r.nextInt(width - 80);
y = r.nextInt(height - 80);


Log.d("","============= Random X :-> " + x);
Log.d("","============= Random y :-> " + y);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the screen width and the screen height, use the following code in your main activity:

```
final Point sizePoint = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(sizePoint);
int mScreenWidth = sizePoint.x;
int mScreenHeight = sizePoint.y;
```

You can use that to initialize your random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

you can check which screen is being used

```
 int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    switch (screenSize) {

        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
        //for large screen
        break;

        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
           //for xlarge
            break;

        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
        //for small
        break;
        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
          //for normal
            break;
    }
```

you can get value of x and y coordinate from **dm**